MUI with Nextjs not able apply global responsiveFont
Need to implement responsive font globally
https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#responsivefontsizes-theme-options-theme
Tried out all the suggested ways in their documentation, is there any other way to implement same functionality using
Tried with this example - https://mui.com/material-ui/integrations/nextjs/#pages-router and still having same problem. I think its related to SSR issue
